# Location of perl libraries

Tags: perl, installation, gentoo

First of all, I'm not familiar with Perl and it's practices.

I'm trying to develop an [ebuild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebuild) that installs a Perl application. However I don't know where to put the library files of the application.

The application's directory structure is

```
binary
share/app/*.pl
share/app/icons/*.png
```

`binary` being the Perl executable.

In the binary I see lines like `require 'someLibrary.pl';` these refer to the Perl libraries in the `share/app/` directory. I also notice a `use lib "$BIN/share/app";` line, which tells the binary where to locate the additional libraries I guess.

Now I face the problem how to install the application.

**Solution #1:** Install the binary in `/usr/bin/` and the libraries in `/usr/lib/perl5/`.

**Problem:** Where to put the icons? The icons are referred in the binary and libraries using `$Bin/share/app/icons/*.png`. This won't work I guess.

**Solution #2:** Install everything in `/usr/share/app/`.

**Problem:** Where to put the binary? Create a symlink in `/usr/bin/` to the binary?

**Solution #3:** Patch the Perl files so they look for icons in `/usr/share/app/icons`, place the binary in `/usr/bin/` and the libraries in `/usr/lib/perl5/`.

**Problem:** I have to create a patch for the files. This doesn't seem like a good/normal way.

Of course other solutions are more than welcome.

**Update:** I've tried solution #2 and as I suspected, when I execute `/usr/bin/binary` the library path gets turned into `/usr/bin/share/app`. This of course results in the libraries not being found.

Comment: I don't think there are really standard Perl practices to guide you in a case like this.  Do what makes most sense for Gentoo and for the requirements of the existing code.  #2 with a symlink sounds best to me, if there is a good reason not to edit the Perl files.

Comment: How is `$BIN` defined? Are the additional libraries specific to this application or is it copies of CPAN libraries and if the former are they contained in a proper namespace?

Comment: If it is an open source application you are trying to package it might be helpful to give a link to it.

Comment: @pmakholm The libraries are specific to the application. The application can be found [here](http://remotebox.knobgoblin.org.uk/).

Comment: @dan1111 I've tried solution #2, it didn't work. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Oh my $deity, that code is horrible. All functions are declared with empty prototypes and then all prototype checking is bypassed by calling functions with the &-sigil.

Comment: I assume it's too late to fix this now, but requiring library.pl files is a Perl 4 practice that went out of date in 1994. The best solution would be to rewrite those libraries as proper modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code uses [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) to locate the applications data directory. This makes solution 2 viable with the script in `/usr/share/app/script.pl`.

If the script was using `$RealBin` instead of `$Bin` (both exported by FindBin) you would just have been able to add a symlink in `/usr/bin` to the real script. But as noticed this does not work with the current script.

Alternative 1 is to write a small wrapper and put this in /usr/bin. Something like this seems to work for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/share/app/script.pl "$@"
```

Alternative 2 is to patch the script to use $RealBin. Either just a simple search-n-replace or just a minimal patch replacing

```
use Findbin qw($Bin)
```

with

```
our $Bin;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
BEGIN { $Bin = $RealBin; }
```

Both patches would be a lot less intrusive that the patch you propose yourself as Solution 3.

I would probably recommend the first alternative. This shoudl work in most occasions and is the least intrusive both with respect to the script and the system as such.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. For that to work the script should have used $RealBin instead of $Bin...